# React/Redux for building web-components

Tags: reactjs, redux, web-component

I wonder of a way to build an app of a web-components powered by React/Redux. This example https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/examples/webcomponents/index.html shows how to bind a web-component to a React-component. But that's not exactly what I need. My intend is to declare a collections of "bricks" like x-dataview, x-sidebar, x-panel, x-modal that have particular behaviour depending on configuration provided via attributes. Besides they expose public APIs.

I would like to liven up them with React. So when having such collection one can build and configure the app in static HTML. Thus consumer doesn't require to deal with the React sources at all, while dealing with HTML and exposed APIs.

Surely I can mount React on such custom elements, but it means a separate Redux store per a web-component, what violates the first principle of Redux:

> "The state of your **whole application** is stored in an object tree
>   within a single store."

So is it possible by any chance to achieve the described above without breaking out of philosophy of React and Redux?

Comment: No. It doesn't make sense. React manages not just a component, but an entire virtual dom. This is what makes React React. Making a new React root for each component defeats all of React's benefits. Trying to do this with Redux is even less useful. Note that HTML components have a shadow dom and React has a virtual dom. Too many doms trying to dominate. Both React and Redux derive their benefits from a unidirectional data flow found in neither HTML nor HTML components. The bricks you want are just React components and Redux is the glue that merges them into s single app.

Comment: After reading docs on REact/Redux I have a similar impression. As it stated by Facebook https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/web-components.html "As a developer, you are free to use React in your Web Components, or to use Web Components in React, or both." but attaching React to multiple roots feels out of React philosophy...

Answer (score 1):

If these components are completely independent from each other, you can just create a separate Redux store for each of them.

This way you can add/remove any component you want and the principle you've mentioned in your quote still applies — you are just thinking about each of the components as a separate application.

If you want the components to talk to each other, you'll have to share store between them, though.